# how to set the new state inside the calculatestate method in Flux?

Tags: reactjs, flux

setting state using this.setState inside calculateState is not possible as it throws the following error: `this.setState returns "not a function" in this code here.` This happens as calculatestate is static and can't be bound to an instance of the object. Is there a way to set state inside calculatestate? 
I would like to set "loading" after a condition has been completed.

```
static getStores() {
  return [SomeStore];
}
static calculateState(prevState, props) {
  const somestore = SomeStore.getState();

  return {
    events: SomeStore.getState(),
  };
}

componentdidmount(){

  //this.state.events;
  //need to do some query based on the events
  //this query will update another store.
}
```

Comment: Can it be invoked from a react lifecycle function, like `componentDidUpdate` and you `setState` with the returned  state value of `calculateState`?

Comment: it can't be set.

Comment: "What" can't be set? You can't call `this.setState` with the return value of `calculateState`?

Comment: calculatestate runs severals times while componentdidmount runs only once. Componentdidmount runs before the data in componentstate has been fully loaded.

Comment: `calculateState` can be called any number of times. Yes, you are correct that `componentDidMount` runs only once, but `componentDidUpdate` runs anytime state or props update. Since `calculateState` takes the previous state it doesn't make any sense to use it when the component mounts.